# Как лучше организовать структуру БД

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Стоит задача сделать функционал публичного или приватного отображения информации пользователя.

Например, на странице пользователя, в разделе контакты, расположено текстовое поле для ввода email. Рядом чекбокс, фиксирующий доступность поля. Таких полей в веб-проекте множество, в разных разделах.

Как по-вашему лучше организовать хранение статуса приватности для каждого из поля, чтобы было удобно извлекать информацию?
Можно создать множество полей в БД с именами всех фиксирующих чекбоксов и в значение писать статус 0/1. Но так как я уже сказал, полей много - то решение не годится. 
А вытаскивать информацию удобно всю сразу для выбранного пользователя.

Можно в БД для каждого пользователя хранить один сериализованный объект вида (IdUser = Primary Key):

```
  var hide = {'contacts' : {'email' : 1, 'phone' : 0, 'web' : 0},  'education' : { 'univer' : 0}}
```

Потом одним запросом доставать всю инфу и в нужных местах делать проверки:

```
  if () { echo '<input>'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

созать таблицу fields, в ней поля id*, user_id, title,value,private (title-имя поля value-значение поля) и таким образом хранить данные, user_id сделать ключом, что бы выборка быстрее работала, id - primary

Comment: Все - больше вариантов ни у кого нет?